# NaiveBayesClassifier too many values to unpack error

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes

I am trying to build a sentiment analysis model to examine some news articles and I am a bit stumped building my model. I am not quite sure what else I need to do to structure my dataset aside from making it into a dictionary.

The dataset I am using is from this thread:
https://forum.knime.com/t/mpqa-corpus/7887/2

```
import nltk
from Noise_Removal import lemmatize_sentence, remove_noise
from Single_Article_Scrape import scrape_news
import pandas as pd

positive_MPQA = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/.../Model_Data/MPQA-OpinionCorpus-NegativeList.csv")
negative_MPQA = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/.../Model_Data/MPQA-OpinionCorpus-PositiveList.csv")
positive_MPQA['Sentiment'] = 'Positive'
negative_MPQA['Sentiment'] = 'Negative'

positive_tokens = positive_MPQA.values.tolist()
negative_tokens = negative_MPQA.values.tolist()

positive_data = dict(positive_tokens)
negative_data = dict(negative_tokens)
dataset = positive_data | negative_data

import random
keys = list(dataset.keys())
random.shuffle(keys)

ShuffledDataset = dict()
for key in keys:
    ShuffledDataset.update({key: dataset[key]})
    
from nltk import classify
from nltk import NaiveBayesClassifier

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(dataset)
```

Comment: Maybe see: https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/naive-bayes-scikit-learn. (Also consider adding () to NaiveBayesClassifier)

Answer (score 0):

The method `NaiveBayesClassifier.train()` expects a *list of tuples* that it can iterate over. When it tries to iterate over the dictionary you passed, it ends up (in effect) with the list of keys. This is the correct way to call it:

```
classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(dataset.items())
```